# How to write equation inside text?

Tags: equations

In the middle of an equation, I need to write to write a very short equation. When I use

```
\begin{equation} 
   stuff >= other_stuff power (2)
\end{equation}
```

I get the equation on the line that follows my phrase (automatic line jump).
How can I write the equation in the middfle of the phrase on the same line ?
Here is the code I used:

```
Only features with \begin{equation}\chi^2 >=10.83 
\end{equation}  are pre-selected.
```

Here is the result and I want to avoid it:
[image]

Comment: Surround the equation by `$`...`$` or by `\(`...`\)` instead of `\begin{equation}`...`\end{equation}`.

Comment: @CharlesStaats Thank you, your solution works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
$stuff >= other stuff$
```

Unfortunately, you won't get an equation number this way...